# Why might Gitlab stop installing PHP dependencies in composer.json from recently created projects?

Tags: composer-php, gitlab-ci

We have a box version of GitLab. There is a group in it called `lab`. In this group there are many long-established projects (PHP libraries). There are also several new projects created in this group. At some point, new projects stopped being installed as Composer dependencies in GitLab CI:

```bash
You must be using the interactive console to authenticate Now trying to download from source Syncing lab/blah_blah (1.0.0) into cache

[RuntimeException]
Failed to execute git clone --mirror -- 'https://gitlabdev.our-domain/lab/blah_blah.git' '/opt/composer/cache/vcs/https---gitlabdev.our-domain-lab-blah_blah.git/'  

Cloning into bare repository '/opt/composer/cache/vcs/https---gitlabdev.our-domain-lab-blah_blah.git'...
Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address '172.20.24.27' to the list of known hosts.
remote:                                                                                                                                                                
remote: ========================================================================                                                                                         
remote:                                                                                                                                                                  
remote: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it.
remote:                                                                                                                                                                  
remote: ========================================================================                                                                                         
remote:                                                                                                                                                                  
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Locally, everything works successfully (the GitLab token is installed). When I try to create `auth.json` with my personal token in the root of the project, GitLab CI starts installing new dependencies, but this is not a right solution. Both new and old projects are successfully included in the GitLab package registry.

My composer JSON:

```json
{
  "name": "vendor_name/test-gitlab-auth",
  "description": "description",
  "minimum-stability": "stable",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "stas",
      "email": "email@example.com"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "lab/old_project_1": "*", // ok
    "lab/old_project_2": "*", // ok
    "lab/blah_blah": "*" // failture 
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://gitlabdev.our-domain/api/v4/group/9/-/packages/composer" // lab group registry
    }
  ]
}
```

Why might GitLab behave differently with new and old projects? Their settings in GitLab are identical, as far as I can tell, and have rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should not be any issues with the Composer dependencies in GitLab CI. To make sure of that, double-check if:

- the [CI token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html) has the correct access rights to the new projects.
- the [`.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/) files of a working old project is similar to a non-working new project.
- [clearing the Composer cache](https://linux.how2shout.com/how-to-clear-php-composer-cache-or-delete-its-folder/) in the CI environment would help.

  ```yaml
  before_script:
  - composer clear-cache

  script:
  - composer install
  ```
- the [scope of the GitLab token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html#scopes-for-a-project-access-token) used in CI covers the required operations.
- the [visibility settings](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/public_access.html) of new projects are the same as those of the old ones.

---

The [OP Stanislav Belichenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6741620/stanislav-belichenko) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77553194/why-might-gitlab-stop-installing-php-dependencies-in-composer-json-from-recently/77553262?noredirect=1#comment136721654_77553262):

> I found and enable right deploy key in `Project -> Settings -> Repository -> Deploy Keys`, and all works fine!

True: the [`deploy` keys](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_keys/) are crucial for establishing secure communication between your GitLab repository and the CI/CD environment. Those SSH keys that are stored in your GitLab project and provide read-only or read-write (if enabled) access to the repository.

In your case, the new projects in the `lab` group were not accessible to the CI/CD jobs due to the absence or misconfiguration of deploy keys. That prevented Composer from accessing the repositories to install dependencies, as indicated by the error messages in your original query.

By adding and enabling the correct `deploy` key, you provided the CI/CD environment with the necessary permissions to access the new project repositories. That allowed Composer to successfully clone and access the code from these repositories, resolving the issue of failed dependency installations.

Comment: Thanks for the first link! Our SRE engineer will check it tomorrow.

Comment: @StanislavBelichenko OK. Praise be to the mighty SRE engineer, the guardian of pipelines and the whisperer of repos!

Comment: It turns out I have rights (I'm a little stupid, yes). I ended up trying everything you suggested and it didn't help. However, I found and enable right deploy key in Project -> Settings -> Repository -> Deploy Keys and all works fine! Thx!

Comment: @StanislavBelichenko Good catch, well done! I have edited the answer to include your conclusion, for more visibility.